# How to pass env variable into application.yaml file in Helidon

Tags: java, trace, jaeger, helidon

I want to pass something like this

```yaml
    tracing:
      service: "test-service"
      host: ${TRACING_AGENT_HOST}
      port: ${PORT}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `application.yaml` is like a static properties file. It is not involved in variables substitution.

Read carefully the paragraph **Source precedence for default configuration** at https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/mp/guides/03_config and observe how to override the properties inside your embedded configuration file(s).

In that scenario you may override the properties you want simply by passing to the **java** command line a custom variable as you expect.

For example, you can accomplish your goal as described below:

```yaml
tracing:
  service: "test-service"
  host: default-host-name
  port: 8080
```

```sh
java -Dtracing.host=remote-hostname -Dtracing.port=8080 -jar your_artifact.jar
```

or

```sh
export TRACING_HOST=remote-hostname
export TRACING_PORT=8080

java -jar your_artifact.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're using Helidon SE or Helidon MP, configuration sources are "stacked" and property scalars stand alone.  So if you do not specify:

```
tracing:
  host:
```

…at all, and if you've ensured that an environment-variable-reading configuration source has been installed, then it will be read from the environment.

You can read more about Helidon SE's proprietary configuration system here: https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/se/config/01_introduction

You can read more about MicroProfile's configuration system (which Helidon MP implements) here: https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-3.3/microprofile-spec-3.3.html#mp-config

Answer (score 0):

For Helidon 3, this seems to be the working convention

For a config yaml value corresponding to this,

```
app:
  persistenceProvider:
    className: com.example.provider.InMemoryProvider
```

You need to export variable like this

```
export app_persistenceProvider_className=com.example.provider.InMemoryProvider
```